# Build everything dynamically or not?

Tags: wordpress

When you build a WordPress site for your customers, do you guys build everything dynamically? I can imagine that some content will be static content, so as a developer you put in the right places. Or is there a technique which gives the customer full control to change everything on the site?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It actually depends on your client, but it is always a good practice to make wordpress website fully dynamic. You can add extra setting page(like theme setting) for all dynamic content like social link, footer text ect. So when you finish the project, you don't have to edit again and again on your client request :)

Comment: Nice that was the answer i was looking for. Is there a special naming for this? Want to search for more information, but i don't how this process is called?

Comment: There are so many custom option framework for dynamically change many value of your theme. You can try [Redux](https://reduxframework.com) or [Codestar](http://codestarframework.com/) for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) too. Using a plugin like this lets you add custom fields on specific pages and templates so your client can edit content which is less 'standard' than the usual `the_content()` area.

Comment: Yeah i know that plugin.. but wouldn't you get allot of tabs in your admin menu area if you use this plugin? For example if you have 4 different sections on the homepage.. you would have 4 tabs at the backend of the site.. am i right?

Comment: You'll only get a single tab in the admin menu - for the main control panel of the plugin, then everything else happens on the page you're editing. For example, if you were to have 3 custom fields for the homepage, then these appear above/below the main content area in that homepage editor. 

Best thing to do it experiment with it, I think - and it'll become obvious.

Comment: Also - you might find this useful too. Hiding the ACF menu from clients: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-hide-acf-menu-from-clients/